# Upsert query for multiple records

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB, how do I upsert multiple files at a time which are in json format?

I am able to upsert a single record by using

```
db.sample.update(
    { name: "harish" },
    { 
        $set: { "size": 2015 }, 
        $setOnInsert: { "name": "hi" }
    },
    { upsert: true }
)
```

But how do I upsert a json file which contains millions of records?

{ "name" : "mouli", "company" : "jp morgan", "size" : 40, "role" : "architect" } { "name" : "siva", "company" : "IBM", "size" : 30, "role" : "architect" } { "name" : "siva sai", "company" : "cisco", "size" : 220, "role" : "CEO" } { "name" : "siva{ "name" : "durga prasad", "company" : "big datamatica", "size" : 50, "role" : "CEO" } sai varma", "company" : "karbon", "size" : 50, "role" : "trainer" } { "name" : "jagan", "company" : "amazon", "size" : 500, "role" : "developer" }

Comment: Can you update your question to include a sample json file data?

Comment: I have record like this
{ "name" : "durga prasad", "company" : "big datamatica", "size" : 50, "role" : "CEO" }

I need to update like this

{ "name" : "durga prasad", "company" : "google", "size" : 50, "role" : "CEO" }

After using mongoimport  
I able to get 
{ "name" : "durga prasad", "company" : "big datamatica", "size" : 50, "role" : "CEO" }
{ "name" : "durga prasad", "company" : "google", "size" : 50, "role" : "CEO" }


I am getting both the records I need updated record only
If the field not exists it should add to the existing record

Comment: Please add your json objects to your question. You can doing that by klick aon the edit link underneath your question. After that delete your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Upsert in mongodb means to update the record matching the condition, and if mongodb don't find any record matching condition it will insert a new document with values you mentioned in query.

Means it can update multiple records at once, but it will insert only one record if it cant find the document matching condition.

**One more thing, you need to add multi: true in options to update multiple records.**

```
db.sample.update({name: "harish"},{$set: {"size": 2015 }, $setOnInsert: { "name": "hi"}},{multi:true, upsert:true})
```